# Django filter by aggregate preserving details

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I have a fairly simple task to filter models using an aggregate value, for example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    page_count = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I need to select all `A` titles that have a sum of `page_count` equal to for example 2 for the same address. It would be easy if I would not need the title:

```
A.objects.all().values('address').annotate(pages=Sum(page_count)).filter(pages=2)
```

But what if I need for every "row" to select all `A`s which are "included" in this row.

For example, we have three models:

1. `A(title='X', 'address'='aa', page_count=1)`
2. `A(title='Z', 'address'='aa', page_count=1)`
3. `A(title='Y', 'address'='bb', page_count=1)`

I want to display only those titles, which have a summary of page count equal to 2 (i.e. 'X' and 'Z') grouped using address.

Is this possible in one query? `prefetch_related` maybe?

Comment: what did you mean by `what if I need for every "row" to select all As which are "included" in this row.`?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
A.objects.all().values('address').annotate(pages=Sum(page_count)).filter(pages=2).values('title')
```

Comment: This will return empty queryset as address and titles are unique for every row (sum of page count is 1 for each of the row). And I want to list out two first titles from the list (since sum of page_count for address ‘aa’ is 2)

Comment: Its working for me and I am using postgresql and django 2.1.